# trouble installing some packages from MELPA... premature EOF parsing tar file

Tags: package-repositories, install

I am running into trouble installing `smart-mode-line` and `ox-hugo`. I use `M-x list-packages`, select package I want with `I`, and then execute with `X`.

The error in Messages buffer looks like:

```
Contacting host: melpa.milkbox.net:80
Parsing tar file...
Warning: premature EOF parsing tar file
package-untar-buffer: Package does not untar cleanly into directory smart-mode-line-20190527.1156/
```

But, I didn't have a problem updating `org` package.

I tried this with Emacs 26.3 and 27.1.1 (both from emacsformacosx.com) on macOS.

The problem is similar to one reported [here](https://github.com/xuchunyang/elisp-demos/issues/3) almost a year ago.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just now able to install that package, so everything seem fine to me. However, I notice that you've configured Emacs to contact `melpa.milkbox.net`. That url was replaced with just `melpa.org` [about five years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2k2kmv/melpamilkboxnet_is_now_melpaorg/). You'll probably want to [revise your configuration](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started):

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Comment: Terrific! Thank you so much, that solved the problem. I was scraping together my `init.el` file from various blogs.... lord knows what other dilapidated settings I have. Onward --- and generally upward --- until the next speed bump.

Comment: That's the spirit!